# What are the demands of the Black Lives Matter movement?

Tags: united-states, protests, racism

I did a lot of research before asking this question, but the lack of (non-conflicting) information is astounding. Despite such powerful and massive protests, there really doesn't seem to be a unified, easily accessable, and concise list of demands that these protestors are asking for. This is in stark contrast to the Hong Kong protests, where the demands were laid out in clear and concise manner.

As an example of my struggles in finding out more about this, take a look at https://blacklivesmatter.com/. A lot of stuff about pledging to vote, buying t-shirts, and donating .... but where are the actual demands for the specific change in society this organisation wants?

So I hope to find my answer here. In short, **what specific actions/programs/initiatives** are the protestors asking for?

Comment: For the  record, it's common for a protest movement not to have any specific goal, at least not from the start. Many revolutions were triggered by protests with no clear objective. A protest can be seen as the expression of a collective emotion: one can be upset at something unfair (for instance a disease) without having any idea how to solve the problem.

Comment: I changed the title and vote to reopen. This is clearly a more general question than the other one which is really about one specific demand.

Answer (score 3):

[According to the Black Lives Matter website](https://blacklivesmatter.com/partners/), one of the partner organizations that Black Lives Matter supports is called the Movement for Black Lives. [The Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Movement_for_Black_Lives) on the Movement for Black Lives includes a discussion of this coalition's original platform. It's six general points are:

1. End the war on black people
2. Reparations
3. Invest-Divest
4. Economic justice
5. Community control
6. Political power

In relation to each of these, there are many specific demands. [The website](https://m4bl.org/) of The Movement for Black Lives includes [an updated platform](https://m4bl.org/policy-platforms/) and detailed policy statements on these areas and more concrete issues like COVID-19.